# Tracking incrementing id's for hundreds of thousands of objects

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have an ever growing list of guid's that we need to be able to track an ever incrementing list of integer id's for.  Our current implementation creates a sequence **with no cache** for each guid.

However, we didn't anticipate the performance hit to the database that generating thousands of sequences and selecting from them would generate.  Due to the number of sequences in use at once, the plan cache is absolutely trashed.  Other queries on the server are suffering from this.

Is there a better way to track an ever incrementing id for these guids that can avoid race conditions?  Each guid needs to start at 1 and increment by 1 without ever skipping a number.  We'll also need to be able to cut over to this new method from our current sequences.

For example, currently the guid 'F642631D-AD28-4943-8340-5E7793EB82B8' will have the sequence dbo.F642631D-AD28-4943-8340-5E7793EB82B8 created and values retrieved with `select Next Value for dbo.F642631D-AD28-4943-8340-5E7793EB82B8`

Comment: "Each guid needs to start at 1 and increment by 1 without ever skipping a number." Y tho?

Comment: I'm not sure that this would solve all your problems, but I don't know what would either. It seems like you're going to have to make some tradeoffs no matter what you choose. [Sequence Tables](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/10/sequence-tables.html)

Comment: @bbaird couldn't tell you, but that's what was decided in the initial design doc years ago

Comment: During investigation i remembered that Option (Recompile) as a thing.  In our dev environment it looks promising, so we're going to look at pushing that up.

Comment: `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` will still cache a plan, it just won't be reused.

Comment: If they can't have gaps, why don't you just store the max value per Guid? You could issue a locked update on such a table `UPDATE Guids WITH (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) SET MaxId += @toIncrement OUTPUT inserted.MaxId WHERE Guid = @guid;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So not 100% an answer to the question I posted, but we ended up implementing option recompile and it stopped the plan cache issues we were having

Answer (score -2):

Did you rule out using IDENTITY columns? [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15)

In a IDENTITY field, you specify the starting value and then how much to increment each time, the most common values are (1,1), which seems to match your criteria.

It looks like you can add one after the fact too, tried it out with a temp table and it seemed to work, see example below:

```
/* Add IDENTITY to existing table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #A

CREATE TABLE #A 
(
Col1 VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
LoadDate DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

INSERT INTO #A(Col1)
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

ALTER TABLE #A
ADD ID INT IDENTITY (1,1) 


SELECT 
* 
FROM
#A
```

It will take time for larger tables, and will take out a schema modification lock, so you may be better off creating new tables and loading them.

Comment: Identity values may have gaps. Note in the question "needs to start at 1 and increment by 1 without ever skipping a number".

Comment: But SEQUENCES are the current solution, which also have gaps.  But IDENTITY isn't going to help.

Comment: @DanGuzman For my own understanding, in what case would an identity have a gap that occurred naturally?...by naturally I mean, wasn't specifically a result of a user action, such as a developer setting `IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON`.

Comment: @J.D., See [Unexpected gaps in IDENTITY column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column).

Comment: @DanGuzman Ahh very interesting, much appreciated!

Comment: for a while now identities in sql server have been sequences as far as i am aware.  by default, identities will cache 1k records and pull off of that when a new one is needed, and those can be lost if the server is restarted (and maybe failed over).  sequences do the same by default unless you specify no cache

Comment: @DForck42, ah OK, I was thinking you may have had issues trying to manually maintain all the individual sequences, good to know about the possibility of gaps with identity, I had never seen that without user deletes, so that was interesting to learn.
The Aaron Bertrand answer J.D. linked to may have a good solution for you.

Comment: @BCM no prob, taking a look at them now