# Can a critical section cause deadlock in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deadlock

We get the next `ID` for our tables from a separate table with two columns, `TABLE_NAME` and `NEXT_ID`. We have a stored procedure which reads the `NEXT_ID` and then adds an increment to the `NEXT_ID`. The work is done within a transaction and the transaction contains a critical section. The critical section was added when some processes where reading the same `NEXT_ID` and causing key violations. Now the critical section is appearing in dead lock graphs. Can the critical section cause/help cause deadlock?

Comment: See this question for the best way to do this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36603/handling-concurrent-access-to-a-key-table-without-deadlocks-in-sql-server

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "critical section" here? I understand the term generally, but wonder how you implemented that in T-SQL.

Comment: Yes, this can - and will cause deadlocks. you want this  to be as fast as possible. Max Vernon points you to an article using sp_getapplock to serialize access to the identity table. I would reccomend that you rewrite the procedure to use a sequence.

Comment: Sequence objects may be an option, but they are not suitable for all cases and have had concurrency problems (bugs) of their own [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011465) [2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3021757)